# Does constructor DateTime take string or ONLY TIMESTAMP type as parameter?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, datetime

I am working with SQLite SQL statement or Query.

So far, I was able to figure out some of things by asking stackoverflow question that can cause problem when executing such SQL Statement.

However, I still am not able to get any result?

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Alarms 
WHERE ALARMSTATE IN (0,1,2) 
  AND ALARMPRIORITY IN (0,1,2,3,4) 
  AND ALARMGROUP IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
  AND DateTime(ALARMTIME) BETWEEN datetime("2012-08-02 00:00:00") 
                    AND datetime("2012-08-03 00:00:00") 
ORDER BY ALARMTIME DESC
```

Here is my table as viewed within datagridView control:
As you can see, I have records from yesterdays and the day before in the table.

[image]

I corrected all the columns in question of their format such as my ALARMTIME, which is TEXT in data type. Still not getting any result, I decided to run the SQL statement right from within SQLite Administrator application as below. Surprisingly, I got the same result which is nothing or nill or null for dataset. However, SQLite Administrator showed me that DateTime accepts only TIMESTAMP as a parameter not TEXT. If so, my above SQL Statement won't work even if I have everything else correct. Am I correct in saying that?

[image]

Comment: Try REMing out all but one part of your WHERE statement, then add them back one by one to see where your problem is.

Comment: @larryr, Hi larry, well my SQL statement does work when I delete just date and time filter. It returns with records, but when I add the datetime filter, it won't return with anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer. From what I understand, DATETIME supposed to take string or timestamp as a parameter, but in my case it doesn't work for me.

Since my column ALARMTIME is TEXT, I am able to query my table with the following SQL statement and retrieve dataset I am looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM Alarms
WHERE ALARMSTATE IN (0,1,2)
  AND ALARMPRIORITY IN (0,1,2,3,4)
  AND ALARMGROUP IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
  AND ALARMTIME LIKE "2012/08/01%"
  ORDER BY ALARMTIME DESC
```

I simply can't convert my ALARMTIME text into datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

try using between 8/1 and 8/3 and you will get the ones for 8/2.

the way you have it should pull up the alarms in between the two times though

**EDIT**

can you change your `ALARMTIME` to a `DATETIME` format?  Then you would be able to use the Between and you wouldn't have to convert the text to `DATETIME`.

if you Convert to `DATETIME` type you will have better flexibility in your query. it will be easier to use in the future as well.

I believe that `DATETIME` is a overloaded text type, so it should output text

Comment: Malione, I just did what you suggested. I am still not getting any results back.

Comment: why can't you Convert to `DATETIME`?